# Using JQuery Date Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, slider

Super new to JS and could use some help when it comes to using outside sources in my workflow, specifically, the date range slider at the top of this page https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/ The site does a good job of explaining how to get started but I cannot seem to get the slider into my file.

How can I go about extracting the date range slider in order to use in my current working file? I assume there is some moving of files into my current working directory and changing file paths but cannot seem to get it to work.

Thanks!

I have used these imports as shown here https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/documentation.html
and moved the JavaScript files into my JavaScripts folder and moved the CSS files into my stylesheets folder but still have no luck in getting the slider to display.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iThing.css" type="text/css" />

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="jQDateRangeSlider-min.js"></script>
```

I then initialized the slider

`$("#slider").dateRangeSlider();`

I would appreciate help getting the slider up and running!

Comment: You need to include all your scripts/css files from CDN or either locally.  Check your console in the browser about issues.